# Chrome gives SSL warning on Google domains

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I've this weird Chrome SSL warning on Google domains only. Chrome works properly with other domain having SSL. Also I don't have this problem with other browsers firefox/opera on google sites.

I've no extensions, tried reinstalling chrome, and other basic stuff like restarting PC, clearing cache e.t.c.

Running Windows 10 Pro 64bit

**edit**
Since I couldn't afford any more delay at my work, and couldn't trust using Google services like this, I had to format my pc and reinstall everything. Now I have a fresh install and problem is gone. So definitely it's not a network issue, but a problem with my pc. If anyone finds the cause and a solution for this I'd be more than happy to accept it as an answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  The problem certificate `GeoTrust Global CA` is SHA1, recent versions of Chrome, are starting to flag HTTPS secured with a SHA1 certificate or HTTP websites that have password fields as insecure.

Comment: @Ramhound this suddenly happened today at work. So you mean there might be something going on with the network configuration?

Comment: Looking at my own configuration, which I admit is at work, indicates a SHA-1 certificate in the certificate path which is what Chrome (the version you are using) is complaining about.  You didn't provide the certificate path though.  The use of a proxy and/or security software that scans HTTPS traffic can cause this issue with Google websites.  Chrome by default will always complain about any Google websites if they don't match the certificate it excepts to use.

Comment: I can tell you its very suspect that the certifcate Chrome is attempting to use is a wildcard `*.google.com` certificate instead of the `www.google.com` certificate.

Comment: Where can i get certificate path? Yes it's very suspicious and i didn't like that.

Comment: Check your image

Comment: Sorry missed that tab. Ok updated my question added screenshots.

Comment: Your `GeoTrust Global CA` issue date does not match mine.

Comment: `Global CA` dates matches with my laptop at home but `G2` dates are different though

Comment: You should look into the fonts.gstatic.com certificate, marked as "canceled / unknown". The certificate you show seems fine.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue across all google domains (including youtube) for ~ a month. Chrome updates doesn't fix, all extensions are disabled, seems like a direct Google bug. Also I noticed sometimes the certs are shown as valid, sometimes not, still only google domains/sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem yesterday. What I did was download malwarebytes software and scan my computer. I also did a scan with Windows Defender. I don't know if that was the case, but I found some Trojans and cleaned them. I left Windows Defender scanning overnight and this morning I saw that the problem was gone. Maybe it was a Trojan. Try it yourself please and let us know the results.